# Unable to create the right query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need a little help. I am trying to fetch records from database on a certain critera but unable to make the exact logic that will work out. Like i have a table in which i am storing some ids like

```
1,14,23,45,17,8,9,11 etc
```

I receive an array like this

```
1,2,19,45,56,65
```

What I thought was to explode the array and match the individual indexes to the column in database. But here is the problem..

If I use

Like %value% query, it returns non required results for  example if we run

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  `table_skills_id` LIKE  '%2%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You can see that 2 was not in the initial array or column that I wrote above but because 23 was present there, it responded that there is one result matching where as it should have said 0 rows matching

What I want is that it matches the whole number rather than matching them seperately. I have tried "Like %2"  as well as "Like 2%" but none of them works properly.

Any quick help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The only correct logic for this problem is a process that is called database normalization

Answer (score 1):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  FIND_IN_SET('2', `table_skills_id`)>0
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: tell me one thing here...it worked perfectly...can i give it an array right away??? like what i am doing at the moment is first exploding the input array into pieces and then checking each entry one by one...can i pass array to this query straight?
Some thing like 
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `table`
    WHERE  FIND_IN_SET($array, `table_skills_id`)>0
    LIMIT 0 , 30

Let me know please
Thanks

Comment: @AhmadNawaz According to the manual it will never work that way `Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string`

Comment: @AhmadNawaz unfortunately it is not possible, you should think about normalizing your data (comma separated ids have a lot of limitations, and you can't make use of an index so they will make queries slow)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  `table_skills_id` IN (1,2,19,45,56,65)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the "in" operator instead like:

SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE  `table_skills_id` in (1,2,19,45,56,65).